# How does recent VMware ESXi (>= 5.1) use unallocated memory?

Tags: vmware-esxi, memory

When an ESXi host is *not* under memory pressure (ie, running VMs are consuming less memory than physically available) how is "free" memory managed?

Does it have some sort of block cache for block devices (virtual disks)? anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If vms are not using the memory then the host keeps it free to be used. The only occasion where this does not happen is if you set vm reservations.

Comment: Could you provide a source reference?